# Pods module not found flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, build, cocoapods

Hello when I try to build my app for ios I always getting this error I tryed many things like flutter clean deleting of pod files and set deployment info but always the same error.

Module 'add_2_calendar' not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `flutter build ios` a Podfile and Podfile.lock will be create in iOS folder

- `cd into ios folder with terminal`
- delete the Podfile.lock file manually
- `rm -rf Pods`
- `pod cache clean --all`
- `pod deintegrate`
- `pod setup`
- `pod repo update`
- `pod install`